# Select em MySQL ordenado pela condição do WHERE

Tags: mysql, order-by, order

Eu tenho um banco de dados em MySQL desenhado assim:

```
id, nome
```

Com os seguintes valores:

```
1, Banana
2, Maçã
3, Uva
4, Laranja
```

Tenho um select assim:

```
select * FROM table WHERE id = 2 OR id = 1 OR id = 4;
```

A resposta que recebo é ordenada pelo ID, pois não coloquei nenhum ORDER BY:

```
1, Banana
2, Maçã
4, Laranja
```

Mas eu preciso que a ordem seja pela condição escrita no WHERE:

```
2, Maçã
1, Banana
4, Laranja
```

Como fazer? Lembrando que o exemplo está simplificado, focando apenas na minha dúvida.

Comment: Se você sabe exatamente quais IDs que vai pesquisar você pode simplesmente pegar baseado no ID como um indice na aplicação (no PHP por exemplo) ao invés de fazer a ordem na query.

Comment: Desprezando busca por performance ou melhores práticas na query, UNION não poderia auxiliar? Algo como: (SELECT * FROM frutas WHERE id = 2) UNION (SELECT * FROM frutas WHERE id = 1) UNION (SELECT * FROM frutas WHERE id = 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, você pode utilizar assim, onde é bem prático inclusive adicionar os valores de forma dinâmica:

```
SELECT id, nome FROM table WHERE id IN (2,1,4) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 2,1,4)
```

Espero ter ajudado